# Is there a way to restrict movement of cards from resolved to active in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, devops-services, azure-boards

Is there any way to restrict the movement of cards from resolved to active Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft added this feature recently (in [Sprint 177](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-171-update#azure-boards-1) update):

[image]

You need of course to use an [Inherited Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process).

See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops#workflow-rules).

Comment: sir is this condition for restricting state transition available for private preview users??